# openssl aes gcm encryption with authentication TAG; command line

Tags: encryption, openssl, aes, aes-gcm

I'm trying to encrypt a file in AES-GCM mode with 'openssl' th/ command line

```
openssl enc -aes-256-gcm -p -iv 000000000000000000000000 -K 00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 -nosalt -in file.raw -out file.enc`
```

Encryption works but I could not find a way to retrieve a resulting GCM tag.
**Is there a way to get it?**

In this document ([link](https://ensiwiki.ensimag.fr/images/b/b3/Cheat.pdf)) I found "Note that it is now even possible to use authenticated mode like CCM or GCM" but still there is none info how to do that.

Or if there any other standard macos tool which could do the same job?

PS: I'm interesting in doing that through the means of commonly distributed command line tools, that's not a question about writing own utility

Comment: You're last paragraph summarises why this question is off-topic - it has nothing to do with programming. Try SuperUser.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note: as user dave_thompson_085 pointed out below, the results in the remainder of the answer are not relevant for current versions of OpenSSL. I was accidentally using LibreSSL `openssl`. Reading a current version of the [OpenSSL documentation for the `enc` tool](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.0/apps/openssl-enc.html), it contains the following sentence

> The enc program does not support authenticated encryption modes like
>   CCM and GCM. The utility does not store or retrieve the authentication
>   tag.

This answers your question, I suppose -- depending on which version of OpenSSL you are using.

---

Original answer, obtained with LibreSSL `openssl` which comes with macOS:

The GCM tag is not stored in the output file when using the `openssl enc` app. You can see that from the following one-liner:

```
$ echo -n 'abcdefghijklmnop' | openssl enc -aes-256-gcm -K 0 -iv 0  | hexdump -C
00000000  af c5 23 59 28 06 0c 06  6e 24 ae bf d7 9d f2 68  |..#Y(...n$.....h|
00000010
```

The size of the output is exactly the same as the size of the input, no tag bytes anywhere.

You can also see it by inspecting the implementation [enc.c](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/OpenSSL_1_0_2n/apps/enc.c#L648). It does not do any `EVP_CIPHER_CTX_ctrl()` call to deal with the GCM tag, as explained in the [OpenSSL Wiki page on EVP Authenticated Encryption and Decryption](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/EVP_Authenticated_Encryption_and_Decryption). In other words, he tag data is lost.

On decryption with `aes-256-gcm`, the tool itself ignores the absence of the tag as well. A message `bad decrypt` is emitted to `stderr` but that seems to come from a different layer than the application, which happily prints the result:

```
$ echo -n 'abcdefghijklmnop' | openssl enc -aes-256-gcm -K 0 -iv 0  | openssl enc -aes-256-gcm -K 0 -iv 0 -d
bad decrypt
abcdefghijklmnop
```

Comment: Look up at line 341 and you'll see that version (1.0.2n) gives an error message instead. Only 1.0.1 base through patch g had the buggy behavior -- at least upstream; distros may differ. Neardupe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27561605/decrypting-aes-gcm-encrypted-with-java-using-openssl Also see https://github.com/openssl/openssl/issues/471

Comment: Ah, thanks @dave_thompson_085 for pointing that out. I did not realize I was using version `LibreSSL 2.3.1` when testing this. I have updated my answer.

Comment: Hmm... that versioning, indeed, is really confusing. Turned out that I looked at a wrong doc. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 0):

Long time since this was posted but, for others:

When it comes to "commonly available command line tools", AES GCM is not available.  The closest thing is probably AESCRYPT, which has the advantage of a documented file format and implementations in a number of languages. See aescrypt.com for details.

Answer (score 0):

According to [OpenSSL man page](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man1/enc.html) under SUPPORTED CYPHERS:

> The enc program does not support authenticated encryption modes like
> CCM and GCM, and will not support such modes in the future.

Comment: Is this an answer?